# TypeOrm find relations with object data mapper

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have users who can have multiple emails associated. I want to accomplish two things given below using data object mapper. How can I do that?

1. I want to find all users in a given array.

```js
const emails = ['xyz@opc.com', 'abc@hdc.com'];
const users = await findUsersWithEmails(emails);
```

2. Find a user with an email.

```js
const email = 'xyz@opc.com';
const user = await findUserWithEmail(email);
```

---

### Entities

```js
@Entity('email')
export class Email extends BaseEntity {
    @Column({ nullable: false, unique: true })
    email: string;

    @Column({ default: false })
    verified: boolean;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.emails)
    user: Promise<User>;
}

@Entity('users')
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @Column({ nullable: false })
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(type => Phone, phone => phone.user)
    emails: Promise<Email[]>;
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I added more clarity to the question. There are two problems that I wrote.

Comment: There is still no question.